# Special characters in flyway.conf password

Tags: configuration, flyway

How are special characters (\,#,:,=) in flyway.conf handled? Do they have to be escaped as in a .properties, or do they have to be written down as literals?

Answer (score 2):

They are not and it is a awful bug. workaround is to set flyway.password instead of using param -password